# Graph in Java w.r.t Time but with smooth increment similar in Ubuntu Task Manager

Tags: java, ubuntu, graph

If you have seen Ubuntu Task manager - Resources tab, the graph increment is completely smooth, the update interval may be different but from a users perspective its a great eye candy

Is this possible in Java ?

just a reminder of how Ubuntu task manager looks like :)
[link text](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/system-monitor-resources.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything possible... You got to use some api for that. Please refer the link:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

You can search for better than this...

Comment: it offers a lot but still does not that eye candy that i was looking for similar to Ubuntu Task manager graphs

Comment: What kind of java application is taht?

Comment: You can also try this: http://objectplanet.com/easycharts/ |    http://quies.net/java/math/plot/ | http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/visualizations.html | http://www.jasperassistant.com/screenshots.html

Comment: and example i found of what i was saying
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY0v4lULjQA

watch at 1:26